# Where is my FileStream-created file saved?

Tags: c#, filestream

I am following this tutorial, but I am not where my pdf file is saved to? Thanks for the help!

```
using System; 
using com.lowagie.text;
using com.lowagie.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

public class Chap0101 
{

public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Chapter 1 example 1: Hello World");

    // step 1: creation of a document-object
    Document document = new Document();

    // step 2:
    // we create a writer that listens to the document
    // and directs a PDF-stream to a file
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileStream("Chap0101.pdf", FileMode.Create));

    // step 3: we open the document
    document.open();

    // step 4: we add a paragraph to the document
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));

    // step 5: we close the document
    document.close();
}
}
```

Comment: or, better, specify an absolute path

Comment: yes you should've specified an output FileStream

Comment: Nothing to do with iText or PDF. The code creates a FileStream, which is responsible for creating a file. Use that as a starting point: there *are* a number of duplicates of this. Hint: relative paths often depend on the current working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be in a working directory of your executable, i.e. next to it. If you ran this from Visual Studio, look into `projectDirectory\bin\Debug`.

Comment: The working directory is not necessarily the same directory the executable is in.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You are right. In this case, however, it is safe to assume so.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably saving the the default location that Visual Studio is specifying.

You should change your `FileStream` statement to define the location:

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileStream("c:\\Chap0101.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Visual Studio defaults can be modified but most likely look in (assuming 2010):

```
\Users\{yourUsername}\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\...\bin\Debug
```